# How to send data via HTML

Tags: html, date, url, send, localserver

Hi I need send actual time via html, like: /time_12:12_1.1.2018 on action on button or automatic. I have codes but I don´t know how to connect it.

TIME:

```
 <script>
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = Date();
    </script>
```

Sending data:

```
<form action="/">PWM:
<input name="PWM" value="50" type="text"><input value="Submit" type="submit"></form>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to submit the date as form data, or as part of the uri?

#### As form data

```
<form action='/' method='POST'>
<input type='hidden' id='time' value='' />
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('time').value = Date();
</script>
```

#### As URI

```
<form id='timeForm' action='' method='POST'>
<input type='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
document.getElementById('timeForm').action = '/'+Date();
</script>
```